# FB login dialog opening multiple times, not redirecting

Tags: redirect, oauth, dialog, popup, facebook-login

i am having problem with strange behaviour of login dialog. **The login dialog is opening multiple times, not closing**... at the end after a while it's logging the user in. Seems like some problem with redirecting. I think everything was wroking befor rolling out "february breaking changes". Can you see something from the url, which is passed?? Many thanks for any help!

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup&domain=dueto.cz&scope=user_about_me%2Cemail%2Cuser_birthday%2Cpublish_stream%2Cuser_location%2Cuser_hometown%2Cuser_interests%2Cuser_photos%2Cuser_relationship_details&e2e=%7B%7D&app_id=179556678746099&locale=cs_CZ&sdk=joey&access_token=CAACjTkwNvZCMBAMkpzAHCEaGhwGngbNgm6ZB96dDkHNj3yIPy5ZA1qJxaKkkQMrYe8KDD0RUZAg8Tr4yyJRBaiZBgH4PJzQFIPJZC9uZBZCW9ZBuTkkjnHFBC4M3p5MMQZAZAbtGDGn9E5FC0XTLtLEDtbGcl2OSllOnZA2AFlFV4JqVZBwZDZD&client_id=179556678746099&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D24%23cb%3Df3a7aa399%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fdueto.cz%252Fffe4e034%26domain%3Ddueto.cz%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df2e889c508&origin=1&response_type=token%2Csigned_request

```
  <script>
    FB.init({ appId: '<?php echo $this->facebook->getAppId(); ?>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) { facebookLogin('<?php echo $this->web_url; ?>', '', response); });
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { if (response.authResponse.userId) { $.get('/author/canfblogin', {id: response.authResponse.userId}, function(data, textStatus) { if(data.isOk == true) { facebookLogin('<?php echo $this->web_url; ?>', '', response); } }, 'json'); } });

    </script>
```

Comment: what is your code for showing the dialog? what language are you working in?

Comment: added the code... the locale is czech. thanks

Comment: found out that "auth.login" was causing this behaviour... still not able to achieve the previous behaviour of automatic login

Comment: this happened to me because I had multiple tabs opened in my browser.=, with the same FB auth link, not sure why this is case.